# How to set a custom URL for Password Reset email that is sent using Django Dj-Rest-Auth, Django Allauth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

so I have dj-rest-auth end points working but I am trying to customize the URL that is generated in the email to point to my front end.

How would I do this?

right now it sends the email with a url from the django server.

http://server-ip:8000/api/password/reset/confirm/{the id}/{token}
however id like to make it so

[http://myflutterapp.com/passwordreset/{id}/{token}](http://myflutterapp.com/passwordreset/%7Bid%7D/%7Btoken%7D)
thanks,

I tried following this tutorial
https://medium.com/@etentuk/django-rest-framework-how-to-edit-reset-password-link-in-dj-rest-auth-with-dj-allauth-installed-c54bae36504e

but it didn't work.